# updating and including two Pandas' DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to update the Pandas' DataFrame by summation, and if the ID does not exist in the merged DataFrame, then I would like to include the ID's corresponding row. For example, let's say there are two DataFrames like this:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ["A", "B", "C", "D"], "value": [2, 3, 4, 5]})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ["B", "D", "E"], "value": [1, 3, 2]})
```

Then, the final output that I would like to produce is as follows:

```
  ID  value
0  A      2
1  B      4
2  C      4
3  D      8
4  E      2
```

Do you have any ideas on this? I have tried to do it with `update` or `concat` functions, but this is not the way for producing the results that I want to produce. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and aggregate `sum`:

```
df = pd.concat([d1, d2]).groupby('ID', as_index=False).sum()
print (df)
  ID  value
0  A      2
1  B      4
2  C      4
3  D      8
4  E      2
```

Another idea if unique `ID` in both DataFrames with convert `ID` to index and use [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html):

```
df = d1.set_index('ID').add(d2.set_index('ID'), fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
  ID  value
0  A    2.0
1  B    4.0
2  C    4.0
3  D    8.0
4  E    2.0
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much for your prompt answer!